# Bower not overwriting bootstrap/dist/css after package install

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bower

I have used bower to install bootstrap and in windows explorer I can see clearly that the latest bootstrap has been installed. However, it does not override my old bootstrap in dist. And I also can't reference the style sheet because href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/ bootstrap.min.css" is not even a valid path. Someone please help me resolve this! Thanks!

I have read things online and have added '    "dist/css/bootstrap.css" to my bower.main.json but there are still no changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/10832)

```
(Manage Bower Packages) is no longer available
```

Microsoft recommend using a different solution. **Library Manager (LibMan for short)** is Visual Studio's new client-side library acquisition tool **(Visual Studio 15.8 or later)**. For more information, see [Client-side library acquisition in ASP.NET Core with LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

And to know how to install client side packages using **LibMan** : [Use LibMan with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2)